# RegisterPostBackControl() lost after postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I have ASP.NET menu and its contents in AJAX Update Panel. It's all working fine. I added FileUpload control, therefore I also added:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).RegisterPostBackControl(ChangeBannerButton);
}
```

Everything works fine (the banner is being uploaded properly) when FileUpload is on the **first page** (no postback, just enter the URL). When it's on the second page (I access it by clicking menu button - AJAX postback), it doesn't work.

I know why it doesn't work (binding is lost), however I have no idea how to fix it. Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score -1):

Surprisingly fixed it by adding to Page_Load:

```
Page.Form.Attributes.Add("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
```